# Canadian visitor after a working holiday visa

Tags: canada, uk-citizens, tourist-visas, working-holiday

I've just finished a 2-year Canadian working holiday visa, and have returned to the UK (I am a UK citizen).

I plan to go back in a month's time for a week to visit friends and family for my birthday.

Will I be able to enter as a visitor, or will my previous working holiday visa impact that? I'm concerned it will look like I'm trying to return to work / live, when I'm not.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are able to obtain a Canadian eTA and meet all the other entry requirements you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just be honest why you are visiting and you will be fine, you may get a couple more questions than the average visitor but they will be just making sure. Make sure you can easily show your return flight home and your connections showing you intend to go back to the UK.

I did something similar after being in the United States a long time on a visa. They were a bit more questioning than usual but I had nothing to hide.